# How to get TinyMCE to always load its desktop mode

Tags: tinymce

I have this page with a TinyMCE 5.10.4 Editor if I load the page at full desktop size, and then switch it to mobile sized, the text box appears as normal, I believe this is because while the screen is sized to a mobile device, TinyMCE recognizes it as a desktop screen.

However, if I load the page in mobile sizing it gives me a graybox that links to an external editor, and gives me this gross empty text area that has my background image behind it.

[image: TinyMCE Graybox]

[image: What Loads on mobile]

How do I get TinyMCE to always load desktop mode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but have you tried overriding the mobile settings to match your existing settings when initializing TinyMCE? This would ensure that even if TinyMCE loaded in mobile mode, it would still look like desktop mode. Something like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'myTextArea',
  mobile: {
    menubar: true,
    toolbar_mode: "wrap"
  }
});
```

The docs also specify that you should include the following `<meta>` tag in your HTML document's `<head>` to ensure it can detect the correct mode to use.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Here is the reference in the TinyMCE v5 doc where I found this info:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/mobile/#configuringmobile